# How to export a midi file from a set of given frequency and duration?

Tags: java, sequence, midi, frequency

How can i export a .midi file from a set of given frequency and time duration corresponding to those frequency. I am using java. In java all I have to do is to get a Sequence object out of that given frequency set. But, I am seemed to be having problems in order to do that.
Please , any help will be apritiated .Thanx in advance.

Comment: And what problem do you have with that?

Comment: In  Sequence object we can only put some standard frequency as some note numbers. Well I don't want to put note number. I rather want to put some frequency (hz) in the sequence or, the midi file that I want to export. So you get the problem ? I can play frequency in form of hz but i can't store them in a Sequence object in order to create a midi file. Plz help.

Comment: Why do you have frequencies and not notes?

Comment: Because for my program I have to calculate only the frequencies and not standardized  note numbers.

Comment: Do these frequencies correspond to notes, or can they be anything?

Comment: In my program frequency doesn't corresponds to notes, but in java library the given note numbers corresponds to some fixed frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIDI is designed to use only 'standard' note numbers.

However, it is possible to change the pitch of all notes on a channel by using the [pitch bend](http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/midispec/wheel.htm) controller.
(For details, see [Converting a pitch bend (MIDI) value to a “normal” pitch value](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/converting-a-pitch-bend-midi-value-to-a-normal-pitch-value).)